# How to generate camelized getters and setters in Zend Studio 7 (for Eclipse)?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, zend-studio

Example:

```
protected $_labelName = null;
```

Should generate

```
public function getLabelName()
{
    $this->_labelName;
}

public function setLabelName($labelName)
{
    $this->_labelName = $labelName;
    return $this;
}
```

But it is generates

```
public function get_labelName()
{
    return $this->_labelName;
}

public function set_labelName($_labelName)
{
    $this->_labelName = $_labelName;
    return $this;
}
```

As you could see - it looks different but i didn't found the way how to change the method name and to trim the set method param name.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the method body (and comment) by clicking

```
Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Templates
```

I don't think you can change the method signature though. I'll open a ticket with Zend and ask for a way to change it. It's kinda annoying that the premier IDE for Zend Framework generates getters and setters that are not in compliance with the ZF code convention.

**EDIT** This was fixed in Zend Studio 8. When you generate Getters/Setters, they will not include the the leading underscore indicating private or protected visibility. Any underscores later in the member name will be kept, e.g. `$_foo` will generate `getFoo()` and `setFoo($_foo)`, while `$_foo_bar` (which is invalid by ZF convention) will generate `getFoo_bar()` and `setFoo_bar($_foo_bar)`

Comment: That is because you don't follow the ZF naming conventions for variables : `As with function names (see section 3.3) variable names must always start with a lowercase letter and follow the "camelCaps" capitalization convention.` (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)

Comment: @wimvds read the whole chapter please :) we're talking about instance variables.

Comment: Oops, indeed, mea culpa. The workaround I posted does work however, so you could use that until they fix it.

Comment: @wimvds no problem. unfortunately your approach is indeed the only way right now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround : name your var $labelName, then generate getters and setters, and finally refactor/rename the var so it becomes $_labelName. Works in Zend Studio 7.2 (just downloaded the trial to check it :p).